# Print a list inside a dictionary without brackets

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The following code:

```
a={"hello":[23,],90:["Hi",],25:[54,]}
for i in a:
    hrs=print(a[i],": ")
```

Has this output:

```
[23]:
["Hi"]:
[25]:
```

Whereas I need the output to be printed without the brackets like:

```
23:
"Hi":
25:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
a={"hello":[23,],90:["Hi",],25:[54,]}
for i in a:
    print(repr(a[i][0]), ':', sep='')
```

Output:

```
23:
'Hi':
54:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {"hello": [23], 90: ["Hi"], 25: [54]}  # 1
for val in a.values():  # 2
    print(str(val)[1:-1] + ':') # 3, 4
```

1. Formatting.
2. Using `dict.values()` since you're only using the values anyway.
3. We manually convert each list to their string representation and then lop off the `[` and `]` using slicing.
4. `print` always returns `None`. It's useless to assign that to `hrs`.

Comment: beat me to it..

Answer (score 0):

Turn the list into a string before calling `print`:

```
a={"hello":[23,],90:["Hi",],25:[54,]}
for i in a:
    print(", ".join(map(str, a[i])), ": ")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You need to use `", ".join(str(x) for x in a[i])` - convert everything to string before joining.